# What can I write as a temporary measure to make a stored procedure throw an exception when invoked?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, testing

I'm trying to write a test that makes sure `SqlException`s correctly bubble up in my code. The basic structure is like

```
MakeTheSprocFailWhenCalled();
try 
{
    ExecuteSomethingThatCallsASproc();
    Assert.Fail("Should never have made it here");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(typeof(SqlException), e.GetType());
}
finally
{
    UndoTheThingIDidInTheFirstLine();
}
```

and I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is even possible, and if so, what should I put for

```
MakeTheSprocFailWhenCalled();
```

and

```
    UndoTheThingIDidInTheFirstLine();
```

Comment: What I understood from your question is you want to rollback something in database in case of failure?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh No, I want some sproc `dbo.SomeSproc` to be forced into a failure when executed, but only for the duration of this test (afterwards I want the db to be the same as it was before)

Comment: Can you create an alternate stored procedure that is guaranteed to fail and call that for the purposes of your test?  For example, insert into a table that doesn't exist or try to jam a varchar into an int.

Comment: @Hambone No, I can't, really

Comment: What control do you have?  Only to change the C#?

Comment: The exact scenario I'm trying to mock up is that of when the stored procedure fails.

Comment: I have a feeling you want to make stored procedures great again.  I had a similar thought as the answer just posted.  Check it out.

Comment: You could try something like `ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myPROC]
AS
BEGIN
 if exists (select 1 from testTable)
 begin
  select 1 / 0
 end


--rest of the SP
END` and insert records from your MakeTheSprocFailWhenCalled() and truncate the table inside your Undo()

Answer (score 0):

To mock up your scenario-

```
MakeTheSprocFailWhenCalled();
try 
{
    ExecuteSomethingThatCallsASproc();
    throw new Exception();
    Assert.Fail("Should never have made it here");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(typeof(SqlException), e.GetType());
}
finally
{
    UndoTheThingIDidInTheFirstLine();
}
```

The `throw new Exception();` would throw a generic exception. In your case, it would throw an `SQLException` anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
Test_SQLExceptionBubblesUp()
{
    ExecuteSomethingThatCallsASproc(); //to check there is no exception
    MakeTheSprocFailWhenCalled();
    try 
    {
        ExecuteSomethingThatCallsASproc();
        Assert.Fail("Should never have made it here");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(SqlException), e.GetType());
    }
    finally
    {
        UndoTheThingIDidInTheFirstLine();
    }
}

MakeTheSprocFailWhenCalled()
{
     //insert a record into testSqlException table
}

UndoTheThingIDidInTheFirstLine()
{
      //truncate testSqlException table 
}

in your SP:

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mySqlExceptionPROC] 
AS BEGIN 
    if (select count(*) from testSqlException) > 0
    begin 
        select 1 / 0 --divide by zero exception
    end 

    SELECT 'SP done'

END
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you're looking for a piece of tsql to intentionally break so that you can see if your code is handling errors correctly. If this is not, the case, please stop here and correct me; otherwise, please proceed.

I have a need something along those lines, and I have my go-to error-invoking query which I use. Keep in mind, that you need a query which will parse properly, though not execute properly.

I use

```
SELECT top 1 1 
FROM [<enter any table name here>]
WHERE 1 = 'A'
```

As for having this fail just when testing, I've seen an approach, introduced to me by Brent Ozar (cannot find reference to that now) which uses a parameter passed into the sproc letting it know whether or not it is debugging or not. You can have a begin/end section in your sproc which will only be executed if the debug parameter is set to 1 (debugging).

This way, you can pass a 1 for debugging and a 0 once you get to production, and only execute the aforementioned code snippet if they debug flag = 1.